# Unix command line wait until file exists in directory

Tags: shell

I copy 100 files from one Unix computer to another.
I want to wait until all files are transferred to measure the time.
So i check whether the last file with number 100 exists.

```
while  [ ! -f  "/path/file100" ] ;
do echo "not arrived yet" >> /path/result.txt ; 
done
```

Nothing is written into the result file.
So what is wrong here?

Comment: You are running that on the target machine? Does the loop terminate immediately or loop forever? If it loops forever then it should be writing output. Why are you timing on the target end? Why not on the sending end (either with `time` or with `date` before and after the transfer command(s))?

Comment: yes on the target, because on the sending end my process shows me that everything has been transmitted , although that is not the case. So i want to do it this way.

Comment: If Linux, use [`inotifywait`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/inotifywait.1.html)

Comment: What do you mean the sending end says it has finished but it actually hasn't? How are you doing the transfer?

Comment: @glennjackman could you provide an example, i do not understand how that works

Comment: @EtanReisner it is a BPEL process with extension activities, and the extension activity just tells me that it sent all files and finished, but in fact on the Linux end the files are still being copied. So my measured time is wrong.

Comment: I haven't used it myself. No doubt lots of examples here on stackoverflow

Comment: that inotifywait works with two different shell windows, i need a onliner in one window without interaction

Answer (score -1):

You don't need those semicolons at the end of shell script lines if its a script file. Removed and tested this as working on my computer.

```
while  [ ! -f  "/path/file100" ]
do
    echo "not arrived yet" >> /path/result.txt
done
```

Also, if you are running this from the terminal and not a shell script you need to output at the end, not in the middle:

```
while  [ ! -f  "/path/file100" ]; do echo "not arrived yet"; done >> /path/result.txt
```

Comment: I don't think that last bit is accurate (or I don't understand it). What are you working around/fixing/etc. there?

Comment: @EtanReisner you asking me or Andy

Comment: @sakal Andy, about the "terminal vs. script" redirection comment.

Comment: If you type it straight into the terminal with the output after the echo comment then it will echo out to the terminal window. By adding the output to the end, it still writes to the file properly. Least that was my experience whilst testing.

Comment: in neither case i get a result, what am i doing wrong? i imagine this kind of task is required quite often.

Comment: Firstly, are you sure that the file isn't there already - you haven't written a conclusion statement so if it's there then there will be no output. (Side note: why output to a text file and not just the terminal?) And lastly, where are you outputting the text file to? Do you have write permissions? If in doubt, change the path to your home directory as should definitely have write permissions there.